# Is torsion-free affine connection not unique, but there is only one that is compatible with the metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, gauge-theory

On page 79 of David Bleecker's book [Gauge Theory and Variational Principles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A73FDD4), the author states a theorem:

> **6.2.5 Theorem**. There is a unique connection $\theta$ (called the **Levi-Civita connection**) on $F(M)$ with vanishing torsion form (i.e. $D^{\theta}\phi=0$).

However, the whole book does not mention the concept of metric-compatibility at all, which I believe is a defining property of Levi-Civita connection. So my question is: how is the metric-compatibility of this unique connection $\theta$ encoded?

In fact, I think this theorem is wrong, and the correct one should be:

> **My Claim**. For any affine connection $\theta$ on $F(M)$, there is a unique connection $\sigma_\theta$ on $F(M)$ such that $\theta+\sigma_\theta$ is torsion-free. For different $\theta$, $\theta+\sigma_\theta$ may differ. Thus, on any manifold there may be several torsion-free affine connections. However, if the manifold is pseudo-Riemannian and we further require  $\theta$ to be compatible with the metric, there is only a unique one left among those torsion-free affine connections.

Following is my argument. First of all, the proof of Theorem 6.2.5 in the book seems to prove only my statement, i.e. for any given $\omega$ there is a unique $\sigma_\omega$ such that $\omega+\sigma_\omega$ is torsion-free, but not prove that for different choice of $\omega$ those two are the same.

Furthermore, if, as stated in the original Theorem, there is a globally unique torsion-free connection, in the affine sense, regardless of metric, there is no way to guarantee that this connection is metric-compatible when the manifold is equipped with a Riemainnian metric, contradicting the fundamental theorem of pseudo-Riemannian geometry.

Following are some searches I have done. I found an entry named [Metric connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contorsion_tensor) on wiki. It has a section [Riemannian connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_connection#Riemannian_connection) in which it is stated that:

> For every Riemannian connection, one may write a (unique) corresponding Levi-Civita connection. The difference between the two is given by the contorsion tensor.

Then I goto the [Contorsion tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contorsion_tensor) wiki page. It has a section [Affine geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contorsion_tensor#Affine_geometry), which shows

> given an Ehresmann connection $\omega$, there is another connection $\omega+\sigma_\omega$ that is torsion-free.

although this section uses Bleecker's book as a reference and the proof is almost exactly the same as Theorem 6.2.5 mentioned above. I believe the editor has modified the conclusion of that theorem.

Am I right?